# Alternative to using java applet for bank websites

Tags: web, applet, onlinebanking

this is a question for all coders developing online banking websites for banks.

Why do banks all use java applet for their online banking websites? basically if you don't have JRE installed, you can't use thier websites.

if it is for security reasons, isn't SSL good enough?

Answer (score 1):

BBVA.es, a major Spanish bank, does not use java.

Alfabank.ru, a major Russian bank, does not use java either.

Are there really that many banks that use java applets for banking?

Answer (score 1):

I'd venture to say that your sample is statistically insignificant, because my sample pool (ie. banks that I use) do not in any way use Java applets :-)

- http://www.bankofamerica.com
- http://www.ally.com
- https://www.mccoydirect.org

Answer (score 1):

My bank, USAA, does not use Java applets for normal, every-day banking but does use it for their [Deposit@Home](https://www.usaa.com/inet/ent_utils/McStaticPages?key=bank_deposit) Service in order to deposit checks from, well, home. They probably use Java in this instance because it is easier to access the scanner and to manipulate the images of the checks once they're scanned.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bank in Austria that uses a Java applet during normal banking use, Sparkasse. Here is the reason they give on their site as to why they use Java.

> Since we consider the password an especially sensitive issue, we would like to give it special protection. Therefore, it is our opinion that it is necessary to encrypt your password in addition to SSL. To this means, we use an untrackable encryption functionality that encrypts your password and makes it illegible. A Java applet will be uploaded that can carry out the encryption. Thus, only an encrypted password is transferred to the server. This way we also ensure that no bank employee ever sees your password un-encrypted, or could pass on your password to you, since it is stored with us only as an encrypted version.

[Here is the site with more details about this banks security.](http://www.s-versicherung.at/sPortal/sportal.portal;jsessionid=RmVhLLlQNhtmZ6vyHhSJvWlpfNMZnh9bj2Lpk1WJYw8vGtmTQ2QB!169518362?_urlType=action&LABEL_MAIN_zz=35121.343967323&LABEL_MAIN_pc=1&LABEL_MAIN_sh=31c28a8a97d4cfb4666142effc29bb31&cci=09002ee2802373ed&desk=help_en_0009&navigationId=021564831641341190000194&&popup_w_webc_url=Channels/Sicherheitsdetails/SC/sicherheit_schutz_pg.akp&popup_desk=help_en_0009&otherPopup=1&_windowLabel=LABEL_POPUP_1)

Comment: oic, they're using java applet to do end-to-end encryption--password is encrypted on client side, then send over a secured connection (SSL) to the online banking server.

so doesn't this make onine banking websites that does not do end-to-end encryption less secured?

Comment: Just going by their website this does not seem to be the case because simply storing a hash of the password in the database accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that re-encripting something would make it less secure.

I was always taught that way by my Network Security professor, but I never saw anything more scientific than his word on it.

But true enough, If that encryption is made by an hash function, you're password will be "safe" from the bank's employees eyes (log, debug information, etc.), but that's the only advantage I see.

as for SSL, it only encrypts your comunication, on the server side you get your data un-encrypted. But that's not bad news, the server needs to do it in order to understand your orders.